# in c#, how do i convert this data structure into Json

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, arrays, json

In C# i have an array of **Calendar** objects

each **Calendar** object has an array of **CalendarEvent** objects

each **CalendarEvent** object has a **Date** and **Name** property

i want to convert this to Json object but i want to change the data structure a bit so in the json object a calendar is an array of dates and an array of names (breakdown the CalendarEvent object)

i want something like this:

```
var myObject = return Json(new
                {
                    Calendars = new[]
                    {
                         Dates = new [] {myDateArray};
                         Names = new [] {myNameArray};
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<Calendar> calendars = ...

return Json(
    calendars.Select(calendar => new
    {
        Names = calendar.CalendarEvents.Select(e => e.Name),
        Dates = calendar.CalendarEvents.Select(e => e.Date)
    })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For .Net 3.5, you'd be looking for the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(VS.90).aspx). You'll probably want to [customise it](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/02/NET-35-JSON-Serialization-using-the-DataContractJsonSerializer.aspx) to match what you want.

Comment: Oh no, why reinvent the wheel? Are you suggesting to manually use a serializer when the `Json` method already does this?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise .Net had a `Json` object/method. Msdn ref?